# Effect of 'in which' - 'best case in which to suggest'

Tags: difference, legalese, relative-pronouns

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p. 81.

> 4.24. While *Walford* was perhaps not the best case **in which** to suggest that a duty to negotiate
>   in good faith was sufficiently certain, because there were few criteria in the agreement
>   or otherwise to help the court to define what such a duty would mean in practice,
>   Lord Ackner’s remarks go too far in suggesting that an obligation to negotiate in good
>   faith should *never* be upheld: [...]

What'd differ  if **in which** were removed? What's the significance of **in which**? What are some formal terms describing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *deictic center* of that sentence is all over the place. Which entity is doing the suggesting in "in which to suggest"?

Let's rewrite it in a manner that keeps the deictic center focused.

Although a duty to negotiate in good faith is not established with certainty in *Walford* because there were few criteria that would have allowed a court to identify what terms of the agreement could actually have been negotiated in that case, Lord Ackner's remarks go too far in suggesting that an obligation to negotiate should never be upheld.